# How to use NamedDataFrame from spark job server

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-jobserver

I used SJS for my project and would like to know how NamedDataFrame from SJS works.
My first program does this

```
val schemaString = "parm1:int,parm2:string,parm3:string,parm4:string,parm5:int,parm6:string,parm7:int,parm8:int"
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(",").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName.split(":")(0), getFieldTypeInSchema(fieldName.split(":")(1)),true)))   

val eDF1 = hive.applySchema(rowRDD1, schema)
this.namedObjects.getOrElseCreate("edf1", new NamedDataFrame(eDF1, true, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY))
```

My second program does this to retrieve the DataFrame.

```
 val eDF1: Option[NamedDataFrame]   = this.namedObjects.get("eDF1")
```

Here I only able to use Option. How must I cast NamedDataFrame to a Spark DataFrame?

Is something of this equivalent available?

```
this.namedObjects.get[(Int,String,String,String,Int,String,Int,Int)]("eDF1")
```

Thanks!!

Edit1:
To be precise, without SJS persistence, this could be done on the df

```
eDF1.filter(eDF1.col("parm1")%2!==0)
```

How can I perform the same operation from a saved namedObject?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server-extras/src/spark.jobserver/NamedObjectsTestJob.scala for an example

Comment: The above example does not say how to retrieve a Dataframe. Here are some lines from your example. Can you say how to retrieve df1 while keeping the StructType?

    val struct = StructType(
        StructField("i", IntegerType, true) ::
          StructField("b", BooleanType, false) :: Nil)
      val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows(sc), struct)
      namedObjects.update("df1", NamedDataFrame(df, true, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK))

Answer (score 0):

The following works on NamedDataFrame

Job1

```
this.namedObjects.getOrElseCreate("df:esDF1", new NamedDataFrame(eDF1, true, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY))
```

Job2

```
val NamedDataFrame(eDF1, _, _) = namedObjects.get[NamedDataFrame]("df:esDF1").get
```

Now i can operate on eDF1 on the second job as a spark dataframe.